# Apache Flink: What type of record does JDBCInputFormat return?

Tags: apache-flink

I am getting an error related to `setRowTypeInfo` for a `JDBCInputFormat`. The error is below. Clearly the `Tuple2` type of the `DataSet` doesn't like the `RowTypeInfo` of the `JDBCInputFormat` but I can't find anywhere that provides clarification on how to define the format.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project flink: Compilation failure [ERROR]
>   /Users/rocadmin/Desktop/flink/flink/src/main/java/svalarms/BatchJob.java:[125,48]
>   incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality
>   constraint(s) [ERROR]     inferred:
>   org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2
>   [ERROR]     equality constraints(s):
>   org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2,org.apache.flink.types.Row
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

```
    DataSet<   Tuple2<Integer, Integer>    > dbData =
            env.createInput(
                    JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                            .setDrivername("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                            .setDBUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[ip]:1521/sdmprd")
                            .setQuery("" +
                                    "SELECT T2.work_order_nbr, T2.work_order_nbr " +
                                    "FROM sdm.work_order_master T2  " +
                                    "WHERE " +
                                            "TO_DATE(T2.date_entered + 19000000,'yyymmdd') >= CURRENT_DATE - 14 " +
                                            "AND T2.W_O_TYPE = 'TC' " +
                                            "AND T2.OFFICE_ONLY_FLG = 'N' " +
                                    "")
                            .setRowTypeInfo(new RowTypeInfo(BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO))

                            .finish()
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JDBCInputFormat` returns records of type `Row`. Hence, the resulting `DataSet` should be typed to `Row`, i.e.,

```
DataSet<Row> dbData =
  env.createInput(
    JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
      .setDrivername("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
      .setDBUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[ip]:1521/sdmprd")
      .setQuery(
        "SELECT T2.work_order_nbr, T2.work_order_nbr " +
        "FROM sdm.work_order_master T2  " +
        "WHERE " +
          "TO_DATE(T2.date_entered + 19000000,'yyymmdd') >= CURRENT_DATE - 14 " +
          "AND T2.W_O_TYPE = 'TC' " +
          "AND T2.OFFICE_ONLY_FLG = 'N' "
        )
      .setRowTypeInfo(Types.ROW(Types.INT, Types.INT))
      .finish()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

got it going

```
TypeInformation[] fieldTypes = new TypeInformation[] {
        BasicTypeInfo.BIG_DEC_TYPE_INFO,
        BasicTypeInfo.BIG_DEC_TYPE_INFO
};

RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);
JDBCInputFormatBuilder inputBuilder =
        JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat().setDrivername("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").setDBUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ipaddress:1521/sdmprd").setQuery("" +
                "SELECT T2.work_order_nbr  , T2.work_order_nbr  " +
                "FROM sdm.work_order_master T2  " +
                "WHERE " +
                "TO_DATE(T2.date_entered + 19000000,'yyyymmdd') >= CURRENT_DATE - 14 " +
                "AND T2.W_O_TYPE = 'TC' " +
                "AND T2.OFFICE_ONLY_FLG = 'N' " +
                "").setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo).setUsername(“user”).setPassword(“pass”);
DataSet<Row> source = env.createInput(inputBuilder.finish());
```